# Add onload function to an opening window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to add an `onload` function to an opened window? (target is "self", not `window.open`, just a regular link)

Is it possible with `onbeforeunload` or something? Or add `onclick` to the "normal link"?

I mean like this:

```
<a href="page2.htm" onclick="theWindowIHaveOpened.onload = function(){alert('loaded')}">...
```

Comment: Why would you need to add an onload function after the page has loaded?  It wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an onclick handler on the link and an external chunk of script, you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadHandler()
{
    // do stuff
}

function clickHandler(elem)
{
    h = window.open();
    h.onload = loadHandler;
    h.location.href = elem.getAttribute('href');
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="page2.htm" onclick="return clickHandler(this);">Linky</a>
```

Though of course you may need to do some work with that to get it working cross-browser.

**Edit** Added the `return` statements so that normal navigation of the `<a>` tag is suppressed.

Comment: Question states no window.open

Comment: Oh yes, whoops. Sorry, ignore my idea then! Yes, with no use of window.open() you cannot get a reference to the new window in order to manipulate it. Is there a particular reason for the fact that you can crate an onclick handler, but cannot use window.open()?

Comment: only the "target" is the problem...
i need to open the window to "_self" and this opens the page in a new window.

Comment: So you need the link to load in the current window, but set up something to happen when the page it points to finishes loading? Do you have control over the page it points to? If not, then I'm afraid there's nothing you can do. If you do have control over it, let me know and I'll edit my original answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have no control over the next page with a basic http call of a link.