# onload event not fired more than once for child windows

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider this case:

```
var openWindow = function (name) {
    var win = window.open("/", name);

    document.write("Opening window: " + name + "<br />");
    win.onload = function () {
        document.write("Opened window: " + name + "<br />");
    };
};

var openAsdf = openWindow.bind(null, "asdf");
openAsdf();
setTimeout(openAsdf, 3000);
```

(See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGnfp/21/))

Don't close the window before the three seconds is up. You will notice the second load event isn't called (even though the page in the window seems to refresh). Why not? And how can I determine when an existing window refreshes, or is called again?

Comment: Your jsFiddle throws a Javascript error when attempting to call `win.onload = function () {`.

Comment: What browser are you using? No error in Chrome 16.

Answer (score 1):

Hook up your onload event BEFORE you open the window. By the time it opens it may have already fired.

See: [Add onload function to an opening window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185305/add-onload-function-to-an-opening-window)

Comment: I don't see how that's possible... I don't have the `win` variable until I call `window.open`, so I can't set it's `onload` property until then. But anyway, the order shouldn't matter because javascript execution in the browser is single-threaded. It shouldn't be possible for the window to finish loading at least until the function exits.

Comment: [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGnfp/23/) to try this suggestion. In this case, neither of the handlers get called. It seems when the window's location is changed, the `window.onload` property gets overwritten as the new location loads.